# Any limits there for <cfpdf> merge?

Tags: pdf, merge, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfpdf

I am experiencing performance issues while writing and merging thousands of PDF files into single PDF file. Each PDF file is about 1.76MB. My JVM heap size is default of 512 only. I've increased the JAVA heap size to 2048 MB. The following code write the pdf form fields for 1000 pdfs and merge the 1000 pdfs as single. More than 1000 pdfs it throws the following error log in coldfusion-out.log file.

Dec 30, 2016 18:43:12 PM Information [scheduler-1] - Run Client Storage Purge

How can I resolve this?

I am using the following code to write some pdf fields and merge as single pdf:

```
<cfset outputFilePath = "PDF_#dateformat(now(),"dd_mm_yyyy")#">
<cfloop from="1" to="1500" index="i">
    <cfset RandToken = createUUID()>
    <cfset inputFileName = "Test-cert.pdf">
    <cfif directoryExists("C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\outputPDF\#outputFilePath#") EQ false>       
        <cfdirectory action="create" directory="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\outputPDF\#outputFilePath#">   
    </cfif>
    <cfset OutputFile = "outputPDF/#outputFilePath#/#RandToken#_outputPDF.pdf">
    <cfpdfform source="#inputFileName#" destination="#OutputFile#" action="populate">
        <cfloop from="1" to="10" index="CurrentField">
            <cfset FormField = "BirthDate">
            <cfset FormValue = "12/24/1987">
            <cfpdfformparam name="#FormField#" value="#FormValue#" />   
        </cfloop>   
        <cfloop from="1" to="3" index="Fieldvalue">
            <cfset FormField = "fullName">
            <cfset WorkingText = "Sathish#Fieldvalue#">
            <cfpdfformparam name="#FormField#" value="#WorkingText#" />
        </cfloop>
    </cfpdfform>
    <cfpdf action="write" flatten="yes" overwrite="yes" source="#OutputFile#" destination="#OutputFile#">   
</cfloop>

<cfpdf action="merge"  directory="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\outputPDF\#outputFilePath#" order="name" ascending="yes" stoponerror="false" overwrite="yes" destination="mergedPDf.pdf" />

<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\outputPDF\#outputFilePath#" recurse="yes" name="resultOfZip"/>
<cfloop query="resultOfZip">
    <cffile action="delete" file="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\outputPDF\#outputFilePath#\#resultOfZip.NAME#">
</cfloop>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='inline;filename="mergedPDf.pdf"'>
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="mergedPDf.pdf" deleteFile="yes">
```

I am running this above code on the following configuration machine:
windows 10, RAM 6 GB, CF10
Can anyone suggest how I might merge all the files into a single pdf?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "performance" issue?  What are your JVM settings for heap size and have you monitored memory usage with a tool like FusionReactor.  I would expect you to need quite a lot of RAM and patience to merge a PDF that's almost 2GBs in size!

Comment: My JVM settings of heap size is default 512 only. I think that is the cause of the issue. I will increase the heap size. Thank you @BradWood.

Comment: I agree with Brad. you need to elaborate a little more. What you are trying to do will consume a lot of resources. You will need to look at your hardware, and adjust settings in the console to optimize your coldfusion instance. 

Other than that.. you are trying to accomplish a large task load. Even doing 1000 pdfs on my 16 core server with 256GB of RAM takes a little time..

Comment: Oh! Now i changed the heap size maximum is 2048 MB in my machine. PDF has merged as single file. Thank you @Tim

Comment: I've had issues with client-uploaded PDFs not being detected as valid PDFs and have had to use command line tools as an alternative to merge (and found it can be faster and require less memory.)

Comment: @BradWood While merging the pdf i got this error in coldfusion-out.log file. "Dec 30, 2016 18:43:12 PM Information [scheduler-1] - Run Client Storage Purge" even after set heap space max size 2048 MB.

Comment: Here i mentioned the loop to value 1500 is sample. actually the loop is using for query. The query maybe have more than 4000 records. I would like to mentioned that here.

Comment: The `Run Client Storage Purge` messages that you are seeing in the logs are not errors. Those are just informational and ColdFusion always runs that on a schedule. That has nothing to do with your issue. I don't think combining several thousands PDFs into a single PDF is the best approach. What are you trying to accomplish? Given your example that each PDF is around 1.76MB and you have more than 4000 that roughly equates to 7GB of data!

Comment: @Miguel-F The PDF is like a certificate which is having Student Name, Student Details, Education Details, Institute Name and Institude address. The institute wants all the students certificates as single pdf. So, I am trying to generate as single pdf.

Comment: How are those certificate PDFs being generated? Perhaps you can gather the information from the source instead of from the generated PDF files.